# В чём ошибка? Tabs и space

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Пишет что ошибка в tabs и space, но видно что табы и пробелы поставлены правильно, как так получается?
[image: Ошибка]

Такая же ошибка в If

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы используете vs code. Попробуйте следующие действия:
В правом нижнем углу vs code есть кнопка(она может у вас называться `размер интервала табуляции`)
Нажмите на неё, далее действуйте по след. двум скриншотам.
Выделите весь код и выполните действие с последнего скриншота
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй поиск по документу и заменить все табы на пробелы(4). Вероятно где-то недостаёт пробела и редактор растягивает символ табуляции.